# How to insert a button on the bottom of every UITableView section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a `UITableView` within my `MatchCenterViewController`, and I designed it to load up 10 rows for every section, but only show the first 4 by making the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return a value of 0 for the rest. What I want to do is have a button on the bottom of every section that when pressed, will reload the data and show 10 instead of 4 for just that specific section.

I've started working on the framework for what happens when the button is pressed, I'm just having trouble with the syntax for rendering the button on the bottom and showing 10 rows for only that respective section. Here's how I have my `UITableView` laid out so far:

**MatchCenterViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "SLExpandableTableView.h"

@interface MatchCenterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemSearch;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageURLs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryCondition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *matchingCategoryLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMaxPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *matchingCategoryMinPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemURL;

@end
```

**MatchCenterViewController.m:**

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *matchCenter;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL matchCenterDone;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasPressedShowMoreButton;
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _matchCenterDone = NO;

    //self.matchCenter = [[SLExpandableTableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];

    self.matchCenter = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle];

    self.matchCenter.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    _matchCenter.dataSource = self;
    _matchCenter.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.matchCenter];

    _matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    _matchCenterDone = NO;

    // Disable ability to scroll until table is MatchCenter table is done loading
    self.matchCenter.scrollEnabled = NO;

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter2"
                       withParameters:@{}
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _matchCenterArray = result;

                                        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                                        [_matchCenter reloadData];

                                        _matchCenterDone = YES;
                                        self.matchCenter.scrollEnabled = YES;
                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}

//the part where i setup sections and the deleting of said sections

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 21.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.01f;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


    _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterArray  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, 250, 21)];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _searchTerm];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.tag = section;
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(300, 2, 17, 17);
    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:deleteButton];
    return headerView;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *currentSectionDictionary = _matchCenterArray[section];
    NSArray *top3ArrayForSection = currentSectionDictionary[@"Top 3"];
    return top3ArrayForSection.count-1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Initialize cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // No cell separators = clean design
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row+1][@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

    // price of the item
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row+1][@"Price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:127/255.0f blue:31/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // image of the item
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row+1][@"Image URL"]]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row > 3 || self.hasPressedShowMoreButton){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 65;
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_matchCenterDone == YES) {
        self.itemURL = _matchCenterArray[indexPath.section][@"Top 3"][indexPath.row][@"Item URL"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WebViewSegue" sender:self];
    }
}

-(IBAction)pressedShowMoreButton{
    self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = YES;
    [self.matchCenter reloadData];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



 #pragma mark - Navigation

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     WebViewController *controller = (WebViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
     controller.itemURL = self.itemURL;
 }


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

for this functionality you can either use special UITableviewCell or a footerView of UITableView

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is for creating a footer for the entire table, not a separate footer for each section, no? I want each section to have its own button on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property `tableFooterView`.

Below is how I use in showing load more option

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

int mySiz = 0;
// keep counter how many times load more is pressed.. initial is 0 (this is like index)
mySiz = [startNumberLabel.text intValue]+1;


// i have 15 bcz my index size is 15.
if ([feeds count]>=(15*mySiz)) {
    NSLog(@"showing button...");
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 296, 45)];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:localize(@"loadmore")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [v addSubview:button];
    mainTableView.tableFooterView = v;
} else {
    mainTableView.tableFooterView = nil;
}

[mainTableView reloadData];
```

Now adjust code as per your necessity...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is for creating a footer for the entire table, not a separate footer for each section, no? I want each section to have its own button on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it like this:

```
// Create "more" button
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    [self.moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downarrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:self.moreButton];

    return view;
}

// Load rest of items
- (void)moreButtonSelected:(id)sender {
    if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == NO){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = YES;
    }
    else if (_hasPressedShowMoreButton == YES){
        self.hasPressedShowMoreButton = NO;
    }

    [self.matchCenter reloadData];
}
```